# FileZilla reports 'Permission denied' but empties file (deletes all file content)

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, sftp, filezilla

This problem is very weird imo. I got FTP access to a site I'm working on, but there seems to be a permissions issue. In FileZilla If I try to Edit and re-upload a file to the server, I get a `Permission denied` error, but at the same time the edited file's content get wiped out on the server! So I end up in a situation where remote file gets corrupted (all content deleted - 0B!), but I don't have permission to fix it.

Most permissions are set to 775 for folders and 664 for files.

- Why could I be getting `permission denied` error? What is wrong with my permissions?
- If I'm really not granted permission to write to a file, why is its content getting deleted?

I'm attaching two FileZilla logs here, one with debugging off:

```
10:32:02    Status: Connecting to [IP.ADD.RE.SS:PORT]...
10:32:05    Status: Connected to [IP.ADD.RE.SS]
10:32:05    Status: Retrieving directory listing...
10:32:05    Status: Listing directory /
10:32:06    Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
10:32:12    Status: Connecting to [IP.ADD.RE.SS:PORT]...
10:32:14    Status: Connected to [IP.ADD.RE.SS]
10:32:15    Status: Starting download of /wp-config.php
10:32:15    Status: remote:/wp-config.php => local:/tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php
10:32:16    Status: File transfer successful, transferred 3.4 KB in 1 second
10:32:29    Status: Starting upload of /tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php
10:32:30    Command:    put "/tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php" "wp-config.php"
10:32:30    Error:  /wp-config.php: open for write: permission denied
10:32:30    Error:  File transfer failed
10:32:30    Status: Starting upload of /tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php
10:32:30    Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
10:32:30    Status: Listing directory /
10:32:39    Status: Skipping upload of /tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php
10:32:39    Status: File transfer skipped
10:33:39    Status: Disconnected from server
```

And other with debugging on

```
10:46:32    Status: Connecting to [IP.ADD.RE.SS:PORT]...
10:46:32    Trace:  Going to execute /usr/bin/fzsftp
10:46:32    Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=6
10:46:32    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse(fzSftp started, protocol_version=6)
10:46:32    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
10:46:32    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend()
10:46:32    Command:    open "gqwp@[IP.ADD.RE.SS]" [PORT]
10:46:32    Trace:  Server version: SSH-2.0-mod_sftp/0.9.7
10:46:32    Trace:  We believe remote version has SSH-2 RSA padding bug
10:46:32    Trace:  Using SSH protocol version 2
10:46:32    Trace:  Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
10:46:33    Trace:  Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
10:46:33    Trace:  Server also has ssh-dss host key, but we don't know it
10:46:33    Trace:  Host key fingerprint is:
10:46:33    Trace:  ssh-rsa 2048 [LO:NG:SSH:FI:NG:ER:PR:INT]
10:46:33    Trace:  Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
10:46:33    Trace:  Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
10:46:33    Trace:  Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
10:46:33    Trace:  Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
10:46:33    Trace:  Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
10:46:34    Trace:  Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
10:46:34    Trace:  Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
10:46:34    Trace:  Using keyboard-interactive authentication. inst_len: 0, num_prompts: 1
10:46:34    Command:    Pass: **************
10:46:34    Trace:  Access granted
10:46:34    Trace:  Opening session as main channel
10:46:34    Trace:  Opened main channel
10:46:34    Trace:  Started a shell/command
10:46:34    Status: Connected to [IP.ADD.RE.SS]
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse()
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:35    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:35    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::FileTransfer(...)
10:46:35    Status: Starting upload of /tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ChangeDirSend()
10:46:35    Command:    cd "/"
10:46:35    Response:   New directory is: "/"
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:35    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::FileTransferSubcommandResult()
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
10:46:35    Trace:  FileTransferSend()
10:46:35    Command:    put "/tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php" "wp-config.php"
10:46:35    Error:  /wp-config.php: open for write: permission denied
10:46:35    Trace:  FileTransferParseResponse(2)
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
10:46:35    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
10:46:35    Error:  File transfer failed
10:46:35    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(2)
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::FileTransfer(...)
10:46:35    Status: Starting upload of /tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
10:46:35    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::FileTransferSubcommandResult()
10:46:35    Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
10:46:36    Trace:  sftpcontrolsocket.cpp(836): List called from other command   caller=0x7f3db4003080
10:46:36    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
10:46:36    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
10:46:36    Trace:    state = 1
10:46:36    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
10:46:36    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ListSend()
10:46:36    Trace:    state = 3
10:46:36    Command:    ls
10:46:36    Status: Listing directory /
10:46:37    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ListParseResponse()
10:46:37    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:37    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:37    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
10:46:37    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::FileTransferSubcommandResult()
10:46:41    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
10:46:41    Trace:  FileTransferSend()
10:46:41    Command:    put "/tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php" "wp-config.php"
10:46:41    Error:  /wp-config.php: open for write: permission denied
10:46:41    Trace:  FileTransferParseResponse(2)
10:46:41    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
10:46:41    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
10:46:41    Error:  File transfer failed
10:46:41    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(2)
10:46:41    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::FileTransfer(...)
10:46:41    Status: Starting upload of /tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php
10:46:41    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
10:46:41    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::FileTransferSubcommandResult()
10:46:41    Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
10:46:41    Trace:  sftpcontrolsocket.cpp(836): List called from other command   caller=0x7f3db4003080
10:46:41    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
10:46:41    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
10:46:41    Trace:    state = 1
10:46:41    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
10:46:41    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ListSend()
10:46:41    Trace:    state = 3
10:46:41    Command:    ls
10:46:41    Status: Listing directory /
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ListParseResponse()
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:42    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::FileTransferSubcommandResult()
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
10:46:42    Trace:  FileTransferSend()
10:46:42    Command:    put "/tmp/fz3temp-1/wp-config.php" "wp-config.php"
10:46:42    Error:  /wp-config.php: open for write: permission denied
10:46:42    Trace:  FileTransferParseResponse(2)
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
10:46:42    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
10:46:42    Error:  File transfer failed
10:46:42    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(2)
10:46:42    Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
10:46:42    Trace:    state = 1
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
10:46:42    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ListSend()
10:46:42    Trace:    state = 3
10:46:42    Command:    ls
10:46:43    Status: Listing directory /
10:46:43    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ListParseResponse()
10:46:43    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:43    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
10:46:43    Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
10:46:43    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
```

Comment: And of course do not say "FTP", when it's "SFTP".

Comment: Can you try the same with WinSCP? It has not detailed logging.

Comment: Martin I'm on Linux, and it seems WinSCP is not available for my OS. Do you think there are any alternatives for me?

Comment: At least try a different SFTP client (e.g. OpenSSH command-line `sftp`) to check if you get the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking FileZilla/PuTTY source code, it's clear that FileZilla indeed received "permission denied" error when attempting to open a file for writing.

If the file contents was deleted despite the error, it must be a bug/misconfiguration of the SFTP server.

Comment: Martin thank you very much for all your patience. I'm going to tell this to the owner to see what he thinks.

Comment: Martin, it turns out that I was given incorrect log in credentials for the server. Specifically, I was told I should use SFTP, but it was FTP instead, so I had a wrong port # and protocol. This was causing all the fuss. As soon as the site owner provided correct credentials, everything seems to be fine, although a bit slower. Of course, I did upvote your answer, and now that we've resolved it, I'll accept it too. Cheers!